# Angular 2: ERROR TypeError: .. is not a function

Tags: angular, angular2-http, angular2-headers

I am trying to use angualrio to read from an array from a json file following this tutorial [getting-started-with-angular-2-step-by-step-6-consuming-real-data-with-http/](https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/04/02/getting-started-with-angular-2-step-by-step-6-consuming-real-data-with-http/).

However I am getting the error

```
ERROR TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The error occurs at this line

```
return response.json().map(this.toEvent)
```

The line above is different from the tutorial since `http response` had been updated. `reponse.json()` now return `Body.json()`

To simplify and mimic my issue I have created a json array x as following

```
let x = [{
  eventId:132510417453240,
  title:"Discover",
  description:"do",
  startDateTime:1512316800000,
  endDateTime:1512320400000,
  url:null
}]
```

And then using the line `this.toEvent(x[0])` called the function below

```
private toEvent(r:any): Event{
let event = <Event>({
  eventId: Number.parseInt(r.eventId),
  title: r.title,
  description: r.description,
  startDateTime: Number.parseInt(r.startDateTime),
  endDateTime: Number.parseInt(r.endDateTime),
  url: r.url
});
console.log('Parsed event:', event);
return event;
}
```

Yet I end up with the error `ERROR TypeError: this.toEvent is not a function`

UPDATE (In response to @Yonexbat)
toEvent is in the same scope I am calling it from.
Both function are right after each other in the class as following

```
private toEvent(r:any): Event{
    let event = <Event>({
      eventId: Number.parseInt(r.eventId),
      title: r.title,
      description: r.description,
      startDateTime: Number.parseInt(r.startDateTime),
      endDateTime: Number.parseInt(r.endDateTime),
      url: r.url
    });
    console.log('Parsed event:', event);
    return event;
  }

  private mapEvents(response:Response): Event[]{
    // The response of the API has a results
    // property with the actual results
    console.log(response)
    console.log(response.json()[1])
    console.log(response.text()[1])

    let events : Event[] = [];
    events = response.json()
    //return events
    return response.json().map((x) => this.toEvent(x))
  }
```

Comment: either do `return response.json().map(this.toEvent.bind(this))` or use `Arrow function` like `return response.json().map(() => this.toEvent())`

Comment: @PankajParkar So I tried `return response.json().map((x) => this.toEvent(x))` and I got the same error `_this.toEvent is not a function`. I also tried `return response.json().map(this.toEvent.bind(this))` and I got `Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

Comment: Where is this function toEvent defined? It is obviously not in the this scope. Do try this: var toEventFunction= this.toEvent; return response.json().map((x) => toEventFunction(x));

Comment: @yonexbat your comment seems valid .. it does not seem that it is in the same scope .. however they are both functions of the same classes .. I have added an update to address your comment

Comment: Is response.json() really an array? You see that in the debugger. You can also try  .map((x) => {code of toEvent here instead calling it});

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not a solution but here I can format the text. I tried this and this works in Chrome:

```
import {Event} from './Event';

export class Test {

    private toEvent(r: number): Event {
        const event: Event = new Event();
        return event;
    }

    public mapEvents(): Event[] {
        const input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        return input.map((x) => this.toEvent(x));
    }

}
```

Possibly response.json() is a promise, and not an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

Try

```
const toEventFunction = this.toEvent;
response.json().then(data => {
   let result = data.map(x => toEventFunction(x));
});
```

Comment: actually the response.json() is not a promise .. It is just the response's body in json format .. that why when I tried it it did not work